# static files not found error in nginix after a correct path mentiond

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

server {
listen 443 ssl; # Listen on port 443 for HTTPS traffic
server_name 54.198.4.208; # Replace with your actual domain name or IP address

```
# SSL/TLS Certificate Configuration
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/selfsigned.crt; # Path to self-signed SSL certificate
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/selfsigned.key; # Path to self-signed SSL certificate key
# Location Blocks for Handling Requests
location = /favicon.ico {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

location /static/ {
    alias /home/ubuntu/logins/staticfiles/; # Path to the root directory of your Django project
}

location / {
    proxy_pass https://54.198.4.208:8000; # Replace with your Django app's IP and port
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

}
this is my nginix configuration and when i tried http://54.198.4.208:8000/static/style.css this url i got file not found 404 error all my static files are present at the correct directory even i tried to open a static file manually by this path and i got staitc files at right path also i checked with permissions also everything is fine but still its not working

i tried manually to see wether the path has static files or but it has all static files at correct loaction

Answer (score 0):

I'm using below nginx config and everything is correct. try this code.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name media.com;

root /path/to/static/directory/;
error_log /path/to/static/directory/;

gzip on;
gzip_comp_level    5;
gzip_min_length    256;
gzip_proxied       any;
gzip_vary          on;

gzip_types
application/atom+xml
application/javascript
application/json
application/ld+json
application/manifest+json
application/rss+xml
application/vnd.geo+json
application/vnd.ms-fontobject
application/x-font-ttf
application/x-web-app-manifest+json
application/xhtml+xml
application/xml
font/opentype
image/bmp
image/svg+xml
image/x-icon
text/cache-manifest
text/css
text/plain
text/vcard
text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
text/vtt
text/x-component
text/x-cross-domain-policy;

location /static/ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    alias /path/to/static/directory/;
}

location /media/ {
    expires 30d;
    add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    alias /path/to/static/directory/;
}}
```